# Bitcoin Fog account to Monero wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, bitcoin

Need some input here. About 4 days ago I moved some bitcoin from my FOG account to a Monero XMR wallet. It gave me a receiving address which I provided to the FOG account and FOG instantly deducted my 400 dollar plus amount. I have not seen the bitcoin transferred to my Monero wallet not has it bounced and been returned back to my FOG account. All my bitcoin is simply missing. Could anyone advise on what may have happened and/or how I can track this or seek help?

Comment: Bitcoin Fog is a BTC coin mixer service. It's not an exchange. So how would you withdraw BTC to XMR? Did I miss something? There's no mentioning of XMR or Monero on [The website](https://bitcoinfog.site/)

Comment: I admit, i may have confused the two and made a mistake. Having said that, shouldnt the deposit/ with drawl attempt bounce and come back to my bitcoin fog account? the whole transaction is just missing with zero trail.

Comment: That must be between you and Bitcoin Fog. I have no idea how that thing is supposed to run.

Answer (score 1):

Various scammers have operated under the name "Bitcoin Fog" (and many domains) for years.

They most likely stole your money:
https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinFog/

Generally speaking, there should not be a away to **accidentally** add a Monero address where a Bitcoin address is expected.  It is technically *possible* of course, but hard to imagine any website being *that* terribly programmed.  If they are that bad at making websites, then they definitely should not be trusted to handle cryptocurrency anyway.